# How can i automate my html form through ajax and php In Laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

everyone, I'm new to PHP and Ajax I want to create a function in my project, What I want to do in that When I select disease Type in my form as shown in picture [image]

When I select Viral Disease so I want to get data of viral disease from database without refreshing the page
[image]

And my code is

```
<legend>Patient Details</legend>
   <div class="form-group">

      <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Disease Type</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="disease_type">
          <option>Select Disease Type</option>
          <option value="ViralD">Viral Diseases</option>
          <option value="InfectionD">Infection Diseases </option>
          <option value="CommonD">Common Diseases</option>
          <option value="NewD">New Diseases </option>
        </select>  

    </div>
      <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Disease Name</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="select">
          <option>Select Disease Name</option>
          <option>2-5</option>
          <option>5-10</option>
          <option>10-20</option>
          <option>20-40</option>
        </select>


    </div>
    </div>
```

This is my Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#disease_type').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).find(':selected')[0].id;
    //alert(id); 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'fetching_names',
        data: {
            'id': id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // the next thing you want to do 
            var $country = $('#disease_type');
            $country.empty();
            $('#disease_name').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $country.append('<option id=' + data[i].sysid + ' value=' + data[i].name + '>' + data[i].name + '</option>');
            }

            //manually trigger a change event for the contry so that the change handler will get triggered
            $country.change();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

This is my controller function

```
class PatientController extends Controller
{
    public function get_disease_type()
   {

    $disease_type = DB::table('disease_type')->get();

    return view('admin/add_patient', compact('disease_type'));

   }

   public function get_disease_name(Request $request)
   {

    echo $request->disease_type;
    die();
    $disease_name = DB::table('disease')
    ->where("disease_name",$request->disease_type)
    ->get();

    //return view('add-patient', compact('disease'));
    return response()->json($disease_name);
   }

}
```

And my route

```
Route::get('/fetching_names', 'PatientController@get_disease_name');
```

Comment: Make an endpoint that returns JSON, call it with AJAX, trigger a form update.

Comment: Can u explain or give me a like to example tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I'll advice you go through some tutorials or content online which teaches you ajax. Here's a link which might help:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

Removed this useless answer since this person is using Laravel.

Comment: great, but be-careful that your sql code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: I'm Also using Laravel 5 for this project.. this code will not work there